# Problems with xml export with WPAllExport

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I am doing a custom XML export with the wpallexport plugin.
I have the case, that I export a multi checkbox. If I export a checkbox with just one element checked it is a string, if more then on it is an array.
The problem is that I do a custom styling to the XML via the PHP functions.

somehow I am doing something wrong.  Here is a snippet from the code

### XML:

```
            [befeuerung({fave_property_befeuerung})]
```

Functions:

```
function befeuerung($meinArray){
        $array = array(
                        "OEL" => 0,
                        "GAS" => 0,
                        "ELEKTRO" => 0,
                        "ALTERNATIV" => 0,
                        "SOLAR" => 0,
                        "ERDWAERME" => 0,
                        "LUFTWP" => 0,
                        "FERN" => 0,
                        "HOLZ" => 0,
                        "BLOCK" => 0,
                        "WASSER-ELEKTRO" => 0,
                        "PELLET" => 0,
        );

            if (is_array($meinArray)) {

                            if (in_array('Ol', $meinArray)) {
                                            $array['OEL'] = 1;
                            }

                            if (in_array('Gas', $meinArray)) {
                                            $array['GAS'] = 1;
                            }
                            if (in_array('Holz', $meinArray)) {
                                            $array['HOLZ'] = 1;
                            }

                            if (in_array('Strom', $meinArray)) {
                                            $array['ELEKTRO'] = 1;
                            }

                            if (in_array('Alternativ', $meinArray)) {
                                            $array['ALTERNATIV'] = 1;
                            }

                            if (in_array('Solar', $meinArray)) {
                                            $array['SOLAR'] = 1;
                            }
                            if (in_array('Erdwarme', $meinArray)) {
                                            $array['ERDWAERME'] = 1;
                            }

                            if (in_array('Luftwarmepumpe', $meinArray)) {
                                            $array['LUFTWP'] = 1;
                            }

                            if (in_array('Blockheizkraftwerk', $meinArray)) {
                                            $array['BLOCK'] = 1;
                            }

                            if (in_array('Fernwarme', $meinArray)) {
                                            $array['FERN'] = 1;
                            }

                            if (in_array('Pellets', $meinArray)) {
                                            $array['PELLET'] = 1;
                            }
            } elseif (is_string($meinArray)){


                            if (strpos($meinArray, 'Ol') == true) {
                                            $array['OEL'] = 1;
                            }

                            if (strpos($meinArray, 'Gas') == true) {
                                            $array['GAS'] = 1;
                            }
                            if (strpos($meinArray, 'Holz') == true) {
                                            $array['HOLZ'] = 1;
                            }

                            if (strpos($meinArray, 'Strom') == true) {
                                            $array['ELEKTRO'] = 1;
                            }

                            if (strpos($meinArray, 'Alternativ') == true) {
                                            $array['ALTERNATIV'] = 1;
                            }

                            if (strpos($meinArray, 'Solar') == true) {
                                            $array['SOLAR'] = 1;
                            }

                            if (strpos($meinArray, 'Erdwarme') == true) {

                                            $array['ERDWAERME'] = 1;
                            }

                            if (strpos($meinArray, 'Luftwarmepumpe') == true) {
                                            $array['LUFTWP'] = 1;
                            }

                            if (strpos($meinArray, 'Blockheizkraftwerk') == true) {
                                            $array['BLOCK'] = 1;
                            }

                            if (strpos($meinArray, 'Fernwarme') == true) {
                                            $array['FERN'] = 1;
                            }

                            if (strpos($meinArray, 'Pellets') == true) {
                                            $array['PELLET'] = 1;
                            }
            }


            //<befeuerung OEL="0" GAS="1" ELEKTRO="0" ALTERNATIV="0" SOLAR="1" ERDWAERME="0" LUFTWP="0" FERN="0" BLOCK="0" WASSER-ELEKTRO="0" PELLET="0" />

            return ('<befeuerung OEL="' . ($array['OEL']) . '" BLOCK="' . ($array['BLOCK']) . '" GAS="' . ($array['GAS']) . '" ERDWAERME="' . ($array['ERDWAERME']) . '" ELEKTRO="' . ($array['ELEKTRO']) . '" ALTERNATIV="' . ($array['ALTERNATIV']) . '" SOLAR="' . ($array['SOLAR']) . '" LUFTWP="' . ($array['LUFTWP']) . '" HOLZ="' . ($array['HOLZ']) . '" FERN="' . ($array['FERN']) . '" PELLET="' . ($array['PELLET']) . '" />');
}
```

---

If it seems to be a array everything is working as it should, but if it seems to be a string value I always get a return with everytlhing e.g.:  xyz=0

Comment: Perhaps change your test to `strpos($meinArray, 'Ol') !== false`

Comment: thx @NigelRen
but this also doesn't solved it.